# Normalization introduce some NaN in my dataframe

Tags: python, nan, normalization

I am trying to normalise my df column by column.
I have tried different methods but they always introduce NaN values.

```py
df_data=df.set_index("Topic")
k=1
a= int (input('Number of class:'))
for i in range (a):
    df_data_class=df_data.loc[df_data['Class']==k].drop('Class',1)
    df_norm=df_data_class.sub(df_data_class.min()).div((df_data_class.max()-df_data_class.min()))
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(9,5))
    ax=sns.heatmap(df_data_norm,cmap='summer_r',linewidth=1,ax=ax,cbar_kws={'label':'Percentage'})
    ax.set_ylabel('Student Name')
    ax.set_xlabel('Topics')
    ax.set_title('Heatmap')
    k+=1'
```

Comment: Why are you using a for loop with `i`, but then not using `i` anywhere?

Comment: I am trying to learn. While loop should work better.

Comment: No worries. I think you might want to do `for k in range(1, a+1)`, and then not do `k+=1` at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dividing by zero, there is always a chance of getting NaN.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN.  If the max-min is zero in your set, you will get division by zero.

Comment: I tried also df_data_norm= df_data_class/np.max(df_data_class,0), this should give the max value in each column. The max values is for sure bigger than 0

Comment: Have you used a debugger or print statements to verify this?

Comment: Printed now. it looks like when I np.max(df_data_class,0) introduces some 0.

Comment: Yes, but this shouldn't cause a problem with normalization.  Only if max-min is zero.  If that is the case, you have to handle that beforehand!

Comment: Thanks, done. I have changed this line [df_data_norm= df_data_class/np.max(df_data.drop('Class',1),0) ] and now works. Didn`t understand what the problem was before and why is introducing 0.